# How to request x amount of objects from server?

Tags: ember.js

How would I go about requesting a limited amount of objects from the server in ember? I have

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Route.extend({
  model(){
    return this.store.findAll('game');
  }
});
```

currently as my route. But say I only want to get the last 10 games?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`query`](http://emberjs.com/api/data/classes/DS.Store.html#method_query) instead of `findAll` and pass in a query param.

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Route.extend({
  model(){
    return this.store.query('game', { limit: 10 });
  },
});
```